# Racket HTTP requests fail with error 10053 on Windows 8

Tags: windows, network-programming, racket, firewall

I'm trying to make Racket work on a Windows 8 PC, but I get the cryptic error 10053 when trying any network request

For example, if I run

```
(define port (get-pure-port (string->url "http://apache.org/")))
```

it just fails with error

> tcp-write: error writing
>
> system error: Unknown error; errno=10053

I'm thinking of a firewall problem ; I got McAffee, but I gave all rights to the concerned programs (drracket, mzscheme, racket), and even when deactivating it I get the problem.

I tried some wireshark, I see the

> (me) SYN (apache) SYN, ACK (me) ACK (me) RST, ACK

And then, nothing.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From all I've found on the web, 1) this is a network configuration problem on your machine 2) completely unrelated to Racket. Your virus software / firewall is most probably the problem, provided the rest of your networking (web browsing, email and so on) works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it looks indeed strongly like a network configuration problem. But there is still some relation to Racket, as I can run a similar command in Python with no problem. But I can't understand at what point the request is blocked.

Comment: Are you running this in DrRacket? Try to do it via command-line, and make sure that the Racket executable you use is authorised in McAfee.

Comment: Well yes I tried in DrRacket, Racket and mzscheme consoles ; and all 3 have the authorizations in McAffee. I'm beginning to think that maybe there is something to configure with Racket, as I ran the same request with both Racket and Python, while logging the exchanges with Wireshark. Both send "SYN", and receive a "SYN, ACK" back from the network. Both packets are identical, except the dest. port, sequence number and checksum. After that, Python goes on with sending the HTTP request, while Racket sends a "RST, ACK" to close the connection.. :(

Comment: Actually... From what I read, the RST packet is probably sent not by Racket but by the OS, because the port is not reachable. So it may be a blocked connection after all...